# Need to draw this diagram using Raphael

Tags: html, raphael

I am new to Raphael plugin can any one help me to draw this diagram using raphael (http://raphaeljs.com/)

[image: This the diagram]

**Update:** The fiddle link of the diagram I created using Raphael http://jsfiddle.net/LG5zn/64/ - I want to make all elements resizable.

```
var paper = Raphael(50, 50, 500, 500);

var rect = paper.rect(10,10, 400, 400);

var rect1 = paper.rect(10,10, 200, 200);

var rect2 = paper.rect(210,210, 100, 100);

var rect3 = paper.rect(135,310, 275, 100);

var t = paper.text(100, 100, "Thermal");

var t2 = paper.text(250, 250, "Corona");

var t3 = paper.text(275, 350, "Arcing");


t.attr({ "font-size": 15, "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" });

t2.attr({ "font-size": 15, "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" });

t3.attr({ "font-size": 15, "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" });


rect2.attr("fill", "#93cede");

rect1.attr("fill", "#72E768");

rect3.attr("fill", "#006ABD");
```

Comment: why cannot you just use the picture?

Comment: Do you have to make a graph, based on some values? Give me more detail

Comment: i have draw the diagram in jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/LG5zn/64/) but how to make it resizeable ...?

Comment: the whole thing or each element?

Comment: the whole thing with the each element inside

Comment: It would be better if you put the diagram or your jsfiddle link inside your question. Now it is confusing what you are asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tmkfs/)** should help you with your project. Just apply whatever you need from this example to your code. ***Good luck***

It makes the whole thing draggable and also click on small square and resize.

```
var R = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500),
    c = R.rect(100, 100, 100, 100).attr({
            fill: "hsb(.8, 1, 1)",
            stroke: "none",
            opacity: .5,
            cursor: "move"
        }),
    s = R.rect(180, 180, 20, 20).attr({
            fill: "hsb(.8, .5, .5)",
            stroke: "none",
            opacity: .5
        }),

// the rest is in the DEMO
```

Also for more info, you can look at **[Raphael's free transform.](http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/)** This is really nice!

Comment: Thanks i will  use this.Do you have idea of scaling the border

Comment: I just added `Raphael's free transform` link. Check it out

Comment: what do you mean. Like shadow or glow?

Comment: maybe you need to have graph with actual scales instead of just drawing squares?

Comment: See this example http://jsfiddle.net/saadtazi/vpGyL/, use the similar tactic for the scaling and add your rectangles